# How to parse nested tags using XSLT in sequence? (Part II)

Tags: xslt, nested, transformation

I got a similar problem like [How to parse nested tags using XSLT in sequance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7763583/how-to-parse-nested-tags-using-xslt-in-sequance/50395615#50395615), but the solution doesn't match

my souce:

```
<BodyText Status="ARC">Lorem ipsum dolor <Emphasis>THIS IS BOLD</Emphasis> amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. </BodyText>
```

the result:

```
 <p Status="ARC">Lorem ipsum dolor  <b>THIS IS BOLD</b> amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. </p>
```

but, I just want a single p  not  p Status="ARC"  because Status dosent fit to my targetSchema.

Here is my code

```
        <!-- ********* BodyText ************************************************************************************************** -->
   <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <!-- ********* BodyText ************************************************************************************************** -->
    <xsl:template match="BodyText">
        <p>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </p>
    </xsl:template>


<!-- ********* Emphasis ***** bold, italic, underline, Default bold **************************************************** -->
  <xsl:template match="Emphasis[@type='bold']">
        <b>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
        </b>
    </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="Emphasis[@type='italic']">
        <i>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
        </i>
    </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="Emphasis[@type='underline']">
        <u>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
        </u>
    </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="Emphasis">
        <b>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
        </b>
    </xsl:template>
```

Comment: Can you add the XSLT you've used to the question? Otherwise it's hard to know what's wrong with your attempted solution. Also, if you could add your desired output XML that would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the template for `<BodyText>`, the attribute values `@*` are also applied.

```
<xsl:template match="BodyText">
    <p>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </p>
</xsl:template>
```

Change this template to

```
<xsl:template match="BodyText">
    <p>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
    </p>
</xsl:template>
```