# How to transform and modify (!) nested tags with XSLT?

Tags: xslt, nested, transformation, xpath-1.0

Take this XML as an example...

```
<list>
  <header>
    something
  </header>
  <main>
    <p>
      (1) nothing <b>special</b> at all.
    </p>
    <p>
      (1a) and <b>another</b> thing.
    </p>
  </main>
</list>
```

Should be transformed to...

```
<list>
  <header>
    something
  </header>
  <aside>
    <para nr="(1)">
      nothing <u>special</u> at all.
    </para>
    <para nr="(1a)">
      and <u>another</u> thing.
    </para>
  </aside>
</list>
```

[This Stackoverflow answer was my starting point...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7763583/how-to-parse-nested-tags-using-xslt-in-sequance)

At the moment I have no real approach to solve the problem. I would prefer not to cite my previous failures...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't remember answering that referenced question, but the answer I gave is the approach to take. You just need to implement a number rules...

1. Convert `main` to `aside`
2. For each `p` tag, add `nr` attribute to the newly created `para` tag based on the value in brackets in the first child text element
3. Convert `b` tags under the `p` element to `u`

It is the second one is a bit tricky, but can be achieved with this template, which makes use of some string manipulation to extract the number in brackets

```
<xsl:template match="p">
    <para nr="{substring-before(substring-after(text()[1], '('), ')')}">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </para>
</xsl:template>
```

(Also note the use of [Attribute Value Templates](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-10/#attribute-value-templates) to create the attribute)

You would also need an associated template to remove the number from the first text node

```
<xsl:template match="p/text()[1]">
    <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(., ')')" />
</xsl:template>
```

Converting `b` to `u` is much easier though (This is assuming only `b` elements under `p` need to be changed).

```
<xsl:template match="p/b">
    <u>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </u>
</xsl:template>
```

There would be a similar template for changing `main` to `aside`

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

    <!-- This is the Identity Transform -->
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="main">
        <aside>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </aside>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="p">
        <para nr="{substring-before(substring-after(text()[1], '('), ')')}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </para>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="p/text()[1]">
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(., ')')" />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="p/b">
        <u>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </u>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you for your prompt reply! I try to implement the proposed solution. I solved the replacement in the following way: <para nr="{substring(substring-before(., ')'), 2)}">

Comment: Wow - didn't know this xsltfiddle-thingy. Thank you very much - worked like a charm! And thanks to possible readers, that they did not consider the thread as "duplicate".